# How to parse below yaml/xml in jinja template?

Tags: python, parsing, yaml, jinja2, pyyaml

Example format for Yaml file
below is a yaml file, which takes xml also as an input.. but should be parsed in jinja code as a template.

```
service1:
  name:
    path: 'pathtofile=/home/example.xml'
    CustomDefinition: |
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
      //some xml content
service2:
  name:
    path: 'pathtofile=/home/example2.xml'
    CustomDefinition: |
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
      //some xml content
```

I've tried below jinja code:

```
{%- for key, value in service1.items() recursive%}
  {%- if key != "name" %}
    {{loop(value.items())}}
  {%- else %}
    {{value}}
  {%- endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What does parsing yaml have to do with jinja?

Comment: Hi @bereal, pls have a look at the example.. maybe i can clarify if needed

Comment: I'd much rather do all the parsing in the calling code, and leave the template to only format it.

Comment: @bereal thanks for the advice , the calling code is python.. but i'm not able to figure how to translate the dict into jinja

Comment: I'm not really clear what you're trying to do here. As @bereal said, you should be performing any parsing in Python, and feeding the results to your template. Please show us what the input data looks like, what your desired output looks like, and what your Python code looks like.